How do I resolve an asynchronous load issue with JS?
I created a new portfolio project to host on my personal website with Kaboom.js and I'm having some issues getting it to load as intended. I suspect the issue is with the asynchronous nature of loading assets in Kaboom.js but so far I've been unsuccessful in resolving it.
The Project:
The visitor to the site walks around a house checking out different objects I've placed. Each object has a dialog box that gives information about my skills, resume, and qualifications. Imagine walking around a house in Pokémon Red. That's the style and gameplay type. I used a sprite sheet and a map for the visuals.
Here is the code:
import { dialogData, scaleFactor } from "./constants";
import { k } from "./kaboomCtx";
import { displayDialog, setCamScale, openContactForm, closeContactForm } from "./utils";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    console.log('import.meta.url:', import.meta.url);

    console.log('Spritesheet URL:', new URL('../spritesheet.png', import.meta.url));
    k.loadSprite ("spritesheet", new URL ('../spritesheet.png', import.meta.url), {

        sliceX: 39,
        sliceY: 31,
        anims: {
            "idle-down": 936,
            "walk-down": { from: 936, to: 939, loop: true, speed: 8 },
            "idle-side": 975,
            "walk-side": { from: 975, to: 978, loop: true, speed: 8 },
            "idle-up": 1014,
            "walk-up": { from: 1014, to: 1017, loop: true, speed: 8 },
            "bag-open": 128,
        },
    });

    console.log('Map sprite URL:', new URL('../map.png', import.meta.url));
    k.loadSprite ("map", new URL ('../map.png', import.meta.url));

    k.load(() => {

        k.setBackground (k.Color.fromHex ("#311047"));

        // Creating a scene
        k.scene ("main", async () => {
            
            const mapJsonUrl = new URL('../map.json', import.meta.url);
            console.log('Map JSON URL:', mapJsonUrl);
            const mapData = await (await fetch(mapJsonUrl)).json();
            console.log('Map data:', mapData);
            const layers = mapData.layers;
            console.log('Layers:', layers);

            const map = k.add ([
                k.sprite ("map"),
                k.pos (0, 0),
                // Controls the scale size of the map -- see constants.js
                k.scale (scaleFactor)
            ]);

            const player = k.make ([
                k.sprite ("spritesheet", { anim: "idle-down" }),
                k.area ({ 
                    shape: new k.Rect (k.vec2(0, 3), 10, 10),
                }),
                k.body (),
                k.anchor ("center"),
                k.pos (),
                k.scale (scaleFactor),
                {
                    speed: 250,
                    direction: "down",
                    isInDialog: false,
                },
                "player",
            ]);

            for (const layer of layers) {
                if (layer.name == "Boundaries") {
                    for (const boundary of layer.objects) {
                        map.add ([
                            k.area ({
                                shape: new k.Rect (k.vec2(0), boundary.width, boundary.height),
                            }),
                            k.body ({isStatic: true}),
                            k.pos (boundary.x, boundary.y),
                            boundary.name,
                        ]);

                        if (boundary.name) {
                            player.onCollide(boundary.name, () => {
                                player.isInDialog = true;

                                displayDialog(
                                    dialogData[boundary.name],
                                    () => (player.isInDialog = false)
                                );
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    
                    continue;
                }

                if (layer.name == "Spawnpoint") {
                    for (const entity of layer.objects) {
                        if (entity.name == "player") {
                            player.pos = k.vec2(
                                (map.pos.x + entity.x) * scaleFactor,
                                (map.pos.y + entity.y) * scaleFactor
                            );
                            k.add(player);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            setCamScale(k)

            k.onResize(() => {
                setCamScale(k);
            });

            k.onUpdate(() => {
                k.camPos(player.pos.x, player.pos.y + 100);
            });

            // Player movement
            k.onMouseDown((mouseBtn) => {
                if (mouseBtn !== "left" || player.isInDialog)
                    return;

                const worldMousePos = k.toWorld(k.mousePos());
                player.moveTo(worldMousePos, player.speed);

                const mouseAngle = player.pos.angle(worldMousePos);
                const lowerBound = 50;
                const upperBound = 125;

                // Up
                if (mouseAngle > lowerBound && 
                    mouseAngle < upperBound && 
                    player.curAnim() !== "walk-up") {

                    player.play("walk-up");
                    player.direction = "up";
                    return;
                }

                // Down
                if (mouseAngle < -lowerBound &&
                    mouseAngle > -upperBound &&
                    player.curAnim() !== "walk-down") {

                    player.play("walk-down");
                    player.direction = "down";
                    return;
                    }

                // Right
                if (Math.abs(mouseAngle) > upperBound) {
                    player.flipX = false;

                    if (player.curAnim() !== "walk-side") {
                        player.play("walk-side");
                        player.direction = "right";
                        return;
                    }
                }

                // Left
                if (Math.abs(mouseAngle) < lowerBound) {
                    player.flipX = true;

                    if (player.curAnim() !== "walk-side") {
                        player.play("walk-side");
                        player.direction = "left";
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });

            // Stops walking animation
            k.onMouseRelease(() => {
                if (player.direction === "down") {
                    player.play("idle-down");
                    return;
                }

                if (player.direction === "up") {
                    player.play("idle-up");
                    return;
                }

                player.play("idle-side");
            });

            k.go ("main");
        });
    });
});

// Wait for the DOM to load before querying elements
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    
    // Closes the contact form when the page loads
    closeContactForm();
    
    // Gets contact form buttons
    const openButton = document.querySelector('.ui-popup-button');
    const closeButton = document.querySelector('#closeContactFormButton');

    // Check if the elements exist before adding event listeners
    if (openButton) {
        openButton.addEventListener('click', openContactForm);
    } else {
        console.error("Element with class '.ui-popup-button' not found");
    }

    if (closeButton) {
        closeButton.addEventListener('click', closeContactForm);
    } else {
        console.error("Element with id 'closeContactFormButton' not found");
    }
});

And here is the error from the Chrome console:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.
    at b.add (index-DfV-Wg4v.js:1:51115)
    at SpriteData.fromImage (index-DfV-Wg4v.js:1:66115)
    at Object.loadSprite (index-DfV-Wg4v.js:1:69732)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index-DfV-Wg4v.js:1:136855)

A few things to note:

The contact form functionality works. It's the map and sprites that won't show.

As you can see in the code, I've added console.log code to check the status of certain variables. Only import.meta.url and spritesheet url fire in the console.

I've tried window.onload and defer.

If I take the assets and plug my website name into the path they load in the browser so I know the issue isn't there.

It did work fine testing locally but as usual, it's a different ballgame when it comes to hosting.



And do you get a 404 error in the network tab of the console for those images? That would mean the url online is different from the url locally. You could try using an absolute path instead of a relative path. For example /images/map.png should lead to https://yoursite.com/images/map.png.

I don't get a 404 error, no. As I mentioned on item 4 of my list at the bottom of the op, I've taken each asset and plugged it into my website domain path. They all show up just fine. That was an earlier mistake I made haha.
